# What is the earliest documented characterization of Hitler as "dictator" in Canada's public record?

Tags: world-war-two, hitler, canada

When did Canadians first label Adolf Hitler as a "dictator" ?

The [CBC Article Rise of Hitler](https://www.cbc.ca/history/EPISCONTENTSE1EP13CH4PA1LE.html) documents that former Canadian Prime Minister Mackenzie King visited Germany's Chancellor Adolf Hitler in June 1937, and that the PM's conclusion at the time was that the Chancellor was "a fellow mystic" and "a man of peace".

In modern times, the widely accepted view in the Canadian public record is that Hitler was a dictator.

My question is, at what point in time did Canadians begin to regard Hitler as dictator? Was it some time after June 1937? Before?

It is entirely possible the Canadian politicians did not use the word "dictator" until some time after public opinion did. I'm for the earliest recorded account in the Canadian press or literature that uses this label.

I would also like to know when any Germans first regarded Hitler as dictator, and I expect this would be as early as 1933 when the Enabling Act was passed, but I don't know how to find this event documented. I suspect much of Germany's public record on opposition efforts was expunged by the Nazi regime as being scandalous. I expect the first documented instance of this characterization would be found outside of Germany, possibly written by an exiled dissenter.

It may be impossible to find the very first documented instance. Any surviving documented instance would be acceptable.

Comment: Based on [The Canadian Encyclopedia](https://www.thecanadianencyclopedia.ca/en/article/holocaust) I would.guess Jewish Canadian newspapers from the 1930s are where you want to look.

Comment: The archives of the *Toronto Star* back to 1894 are supposedly available to "Toronto Public Library customers who qualify for a free library card". You may want to check there.

Comment: I would suggest checking the Canadian Parliamentary Debates (Hansard) for 1934 (after the death of Hindenburg; Hitler then "Führer und Reichskanzler"). Google only gives me useless snippets which suggest that "Hitler" and "dictator" may have occurred in close proximity in parliamentary speeches a few times. I tried to get access to the Hansard at McGill but hit what looks like a dead link. Got a few other search hits in Canadian publications supposedly from 1934, but again only useless Google snippets.

Comment: Mackenzie King was not typical of Canadian thought at the time.